# Difference between this and base

Tags: c#, this

I am interested to know the difference between `this` and `base` object in C#. What is the best practice when using them?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) represents the current class instance while [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) the parent. Example of usage:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    // call constructor in the current type
    public Child() : this("abc")
    {
    }

    public Child(string id)
    {
    }

    public override void Foo()
    { 
        // call parent method
        base.Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: strictly speaking this refers to the current class instance, not the current class type.

Comment: @Adrian, yes good point. Updated my post to take into account.

Answer (score 13):

The two keywords are very different.

- `this` refers to the **current instance** (not the “current class”). It can only be used in non-static methods (because in a static method there is no current instance). Calling a method on `this` will call the method in the same way as it would if you called it on a variable containing the same instance.
- `base` is a keyword that allows **inherited method call,** i.e. it calls the specified method from the base type. It too can only be used in a non-static method. It is usually used in a virtual method override, but actually can be used to call any method in the base type. It is very different from normal method invocation because it circumvents the normal virtual-method dispatch: it calls the base method directly even if it is virtual.

Answer (score 9):

Darin is right on. An example may also help. (There wasn't an example when I initially posted. Now there is.)

```
class Base {

    protected virtual void SayHi() {
        Console.WriteLine("Base says hi!");
    }

}

class Derived : Base {

    protected override void SayHi() {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived says hi!");
    }

    public void DoIt() {
        base.SayHi();
        this.SayHi();
    }
}
```

The above prints "Base says hi!" followed by "Derived says hi!"

Answer (score 2):

"`this`" keyword points to the address of current object. we can use "`this`" keyword to represent current object (of current class).

Where as "`base`" keyword represent to "Parent class"
So if you want to use/call function of parent class you can use "`base`" Keyword.
`base` is very useful in function overriding to call function of parent class.

Comment: Method overriding* they are inside class and not every method returns value(to get called function).

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to any object that is currently being used. `Base` refers to a base class generally speaking.

If the object is of the `base` then in that case `this` can refer to the `base` object also.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current class instance.

`base` refers to the base class of the current instance, that is, the class from which it is derived.  If the current class is not explicitly derived from anything `base` will refer to the `System.Object` class (I think).

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have code like this

```
class B extends A {

    public B () {
        // this will refer to the current object of class B
        // base will refer to class A
    }

}
```

Note: The syntax of code is in java but it is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

base - is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class

this - refers to the current instance of the class and inherited

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string BaseAttr { get; set; }
}
class A : BaseClass
{
    public string Attr { get; set; }
    public void Method()
    {
        this.Attr = "ok";
        this.BaseAttr = "base ok";
        base.BaseAttr = "ok";
        base.Attr = "unavailable"; //!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use this.function() in a class, the will get an error due to stackoverflow.

Comment: What language do you mean? This is not always the case. This error can usually occur when creating from the same object inside the constructor in C#.